# My Tools folder has gone how to get it

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, recovery

Today at morning about 6 hour ago I was updating tools and installing new features from `SDK Manager`. And due to my Internet connection shutdown Updating process canceled automatically. Now when I try to open `Android SDK Manager` it says

> Failed to execute tools/android.bat.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Then I try to find the `android.bat` file in tools And I realized that my Tools folder is missing with all its components. But  as I know everything is fine except this problem. How can I get that folder back or download that specific folder instead of the whole `android SDK`.

Comment: Need to download full SDK, There is a no way for download specific tools folder. Or you can copy that folder from others and paste it in your SDK dir.

Comment: Oh this is not good But the only option. I think copying from other friend is still batter than downloading whole SDK. thanks

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT If you can get it quicker from a local source rather than the internet, then go for it. Just make sure the SDK location is correct as per my answer, and that all the libraries and platforms you require are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at where the SDK location is defined in Android Studio (*File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK location*) and verify if the folder and its contents still exist on your system.

[image: Screenshot]

If the folder has gone, you will need to re-download the SDK ([link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), see *"Get just the command line tools"*). Download and extract to the location defined in Android Studio, or point `Android SDK Location` to wherever you extract the SDK to.

You will also need to re-download whatever tools and libraries you need, time consuming but unfortunately necessary if your existing SDK has indeed been wiped.

Comment: The location is correct But the link for download is worth of accepted Answer :). With 292MB  download now everything working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need re-install or update Android SDK

Comment: this can't be consider an answer.